# appending a parameter to sql script in python

Tags: python, mysql

Suppose a simple query in python as follows. The python code reads a "new city" from a user. The question is how to update the query by appending a list of cities (e.g., 'city1', 'city2', 'city3') to the where clause in the query.

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "select * FROM my_table 

WHERE (city = 'Seattle') 
or (city = 'Portland')"

mycursor.execute(sql)

mydb.commit()
```

desired sql script

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "select * FROM my_table 

WHERE (city = 'Seattle') 
or (city = 'Portland')
or (city =  'city1') 
or (city = 'city2)
or (city ='city3')"

mycursor.execute(sql)

mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `WHERE city IN ('Seattle', 'Portland', ...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `city IN (...)` rather than multiple `city =` operations. Then you can build the list of placeholders dynamically and replace them using parameters.

```
cities = ['Seattle', 'Portland', 'city1', 'city2', 'city3']
placeholders = ','.join(['%s']*len(cities))
sql = f'SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE city IN ({placeholders})'
mycursor.execute(sql, cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution would require string manipulation like so (assuming u take input to a variable newCity):

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "select * FROM my_table WHERE (city = 'Seattle') or (city = 'Portland')"

#put in for loop for as long as ud like 
newCity = input("insert new city")
sql = sql + " or (city = \'" + newCity + "\')"

mycursor.execute(sql)
mydb.commit()
```